# Filter (nested) boolean field in Mongo / Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Mongo collection (using Meteor) structured like so:

```
{
    "_id" : "xx",
    "name" : "xx",
    "handle" : "xx",
    "tweets" : [
        {
            "published" : true,
            "tweet_id" : "xx",
            "text" : "xx",
            "created_at" : "Mon Jul 31 18:18:38 +0000 2017",
            "retweet_count" : 0,
            "from" : "x",
            "from_full_name" : "x",
            "from_profile_image" : "x"
        },
        {
            "published" : true,
            "tweet_id" : "xx",
            "text" : "xx",
            "created_at" : "Mon Jul 31 18:18:38 +0000 2017",
            "retweet_count" : 0,
            "from" : "x",
            "from_full_name" : "x",
            "from_profile_image" : "x"
        },
        {
            "published" : false,
            "tweet_id" : "xx",
            "text" : "xx",
            "created_at" : "Mon Jul 31 18:18:38 +0000 2017",
            "retweet_count" : 0,
            "from" : "x",
            "from_full_name" : "x",
            "from_profile_image" : "x"
        },
    ]
}
```

I only want to display the published tweets. I am using a template helper to retrieve and filter:

```
return Tweets.find({
    handle:handle,
    "tweets.published": true
});
```

I cannot seem to get the nested filter on 'published' to work. All tweets are displayed, using the above code. I have tried many different permutations of the `"tweets.published": true`. What is the correct way to filter out the unpublished tweets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `tweets` field is an array of objects, not just one object, your method will not work.

First you should use the handle to find the correct document:

```
return Tweets.find({
  handle: handle,
});
```

This must then be combined with a `fields`, to select tweets which should be returned.

```
return Tweets.find({
  handle: handle,
}, {
  fields: { tweets: { $elemMatch: { published: true } } } 
});
```

the `$elemMatch` part specifies the tweet must be publised. More information [on the mongo page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/).

EDIT
If the snippet must run on the client (in your case), you have other options. You can use a server publication with my snippet to only give published tweets to the client.

Alternatively, give the transform option to the find request.

```
return Tweets.find({
  handle: handle
}, {
  transform: doc => {
    doc.tweets = doc.tweets.filter(tweet => tweet.published);
    return doc;
  }
});
```

Comment: `Error: Minimongo doesn't support operators in projections yet.`

Comment: Try my new code snippet? I didn't realise the code was running on the client

Comment: Lovely! I am going to read up on `filter` and `transform`. Thank you Seb.

Comment: Is it possible to then apply a sort to the returned doc, by "created_at" field?

Comment: Yeah. Change: doc.tweets = doc.tweets.filter(tweet => tweet.published);. To: doc.tweets = doc.tweets.filter(tweet => tweet.published).sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b));

Comment: That will sort the array in chronological order (lookup array sort JavaScript)